# Is there a formula for converting a pixel coordinate in 1680x1050 to 1920x1080

Tags: resolution, pixel

I'm playing around with converting some macros for a game (a tale in the desert) and found one I'm playing with trying to convert from the res it was written for (1680x1050) to my resolution (1920x1080).

The macro does a series of clicks on the screen at certain coordinates.
I'd like to try to get it as close as possible if such a formula exists and then tweak from there.

Thanks guys.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
1680 * x = 1920
1050 * y = 1080
```

Solve for `x` and `y` and that's what you'll need to multiply your coordinates by.

Comment: It'll be about a day and a half before I can test in the game (due to certain research in the game not being open yet).

Comment: Guys, there's no need to be condescending about it.  You don't know what you don't know, and there's no need to make fun of someone for it.

Comment: But x and y are not integers here.